# Is it useful to consider properties about box-topology?

Tags: general-topology

Comparing box topology and product topology, there are many better theorems standing in product topology, but not stands in box topology.

So is it useful to study box topology?

Comment: Probably not. The box topology doesn't behave well enough and it doesn't appear often enough for us to care. Actually I don't recall a single useful result based on box topology except for "counterexamples in topology" style results.

Comment: Box products and modifications of box products have a number of counterexamples in topology, including the first example in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ of a [Dowker space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dowker_space). And counterexamples to plausible conjectures are important.

Comment: In the list of related questions there is a question [Is the box topology good for anything?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36420/is-the-box-topology-good-for-anything) with 62 upvotes and 5 answers.